# Cumulative sum for a range of weeks where some weeks have no value

Tags: sql-server

I am using this query to get rolling 5 week sum

```
select reportdate,
    department,
    count(orders) as count,
    sum(count(orders)) over (
        partition by department order by reportdate rows between 4 preceding and current row
        ) as 5 weeksum
from orders
```

sum(count(orders) works fine when there is value for every department every reportdate.
however if there are no orders for certain reportdates then the sum(count(orders)) does not work.

For eg.

```
reportdate 1-Jan Dept A count(Orders) is 10
7-Jan dept A 'NO ORDERS' which means blank column
14-Jan dept A count(Orders) is 12
21-Jan dept A count(Orders) is 14
28-jan dept A count(Orders) is 25
31-jan dept A count(Orders) is 5
```

result for sum(count(orders))

```
1-Jan 10
7-Jan BLANK 
 while I expect 7-Jan to show 10
```

Any suggestions as how that can be achieved?

Comment: Why do you expect 7-Jan to show 10 if there are no orders?

Comment: because I am calculating a rolling sum,..i want to see # of orders over 5 weeks rolling period.

Comment: Your sql looks correct.   I suspect your data isn't what you say it is.   Can you post a reproducible example?

Comment: Case when order is null then 0 count.

Comment: First create Calender CTE for duration you want.Then left join your table with CalenderCTE such that where there is no reportdate then replace it with caldate and isnull9order,0).Write this in second CTE.verify the result then apply your above query in secondCTE.It is is easy infact.